# postgis shape file import problems

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis, shapes, shapefile

Hi I'm trying to import a shape file from

http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/bytesarchive.shtml

into a postgis database.  the above files creates MULTIPOLYGONS when i import using shp2pgsql.

then i'm trying to simply determine if lat/long points are contained in my multipolygons

however my select's are not working, and when i print out the poitns of my the_geom column it seems to be very broken.

```
select st_astext(geom) from (select (st_dumppoints(the_geom)).* from nybb where borocode =1) foo;
```

gives the result...

```
            st_astext
------------------------------------------
 POINT(1007193.83859999 257820.786899999)
 POINT(1007209.40620001 257829.435100004)
 POINT(1007244.8654 257833.326199993)
 POINT(1007283.3496 257839.812399998)
 POINT(1007299.3502 257851.488900006)
 POINT(1007320.1081 257869.218500003)
 POINT(1007356.64669999 257891.055800006)
 POINT(1007385.6197 257901.432999998)
 POINT(1007421.94509999 257894.084000006)
 POINT(1007516.85959999 257890.406100005)
 POINT(1007582.59110001 257884.7861)
 POINT(1007639.02150001 257877.217199996)
 POINT(1007701.29170001 257872.893099993)
...
```

for points in nyc, this is very off..  what am i doing wrong?

Comment: This question will probably fit better on http://gis.stackexchange.com You might consider asking a moderator for it to be moved there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The points are not of. The spatial data that is referred to is NOT in lat/long. This is why numbers are different from what you expect. If you need it to be in long/lat it must be reprojected. See more here: http://postgis.refractions.net/news/20020108/

The projection of the data seems to be in the [NAD_1983_StatePlane_New_York_Long_Island_FIPS_3104_Feet](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102718/) coordinate system (according to the metadata - see code.).

```
<spref>
    <horizsys>
        <planar>
            <planci>
                <plance Sync="TRUE">coordinate pair</plance>
                <coordrep>
                    <absres Sync="TRUE">0.000000</absres>
                    <ordres Sync="TRUE">0.000000</ordres>
                </coordrep>
                <plandu Sync="TRUE">survey feet</plandu>
            </planci>
            <mapproj><mapprojn Sync="TRUE">Lambert Conformal Conic</mapprojn><lambertc><stdparll Sync="TRUE">40.666667</stdparll><stdparll Sync="TRUE">41.033333</stdparll><longcm Sync="TRUE">-74.000000</longcm><latprjo Sync="TRUE">40.166667</latprjo><feast Sync="TRUE">984250.000000</feast><fnorth Sync="TRUE">0.000000</fnorth></lambertc></mapproj></planar>
        <geodetic>
            <horizdn Sync="TRUE">North American Datum of 1983</horizdn>
            <ellips Sync="TRUE">Geodetic Reference System 80</ellips>
            <semiaxis Sync="TRUE">6378137.000000</semiaxis>
            <denflat Sync="TRUE">298.257222</denflat>
        </geodetic>
        <cordsysn>
            <geogcsn Sync="TRUE">GCS_North_American_1983</geogcsn>
            <projcsn Sync="TRUE">NAD_1983_StatePlane_New_York_Long_Island_FIPS_3104_Feet</projcsn>
        </cordsysn>
    </horizsys>
</spref>
```

If you work much with spatial data I suggest that you read more about [map projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection).

Comment: Use the -s flag in shp2pgsql to set the SRID to [2263](http://prj2epsg.org/epsg/2263). Then you can use [ST_Transform](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) to convert to 4326.

Comment: Another possibility - pass ```-s 2263:4326``` to shp2pgsql. Does the conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not issue with PostGIS. I checked input esri Shape file `nybb.shp` with [AvisMap Free Viewer](http://www.avismap.com/downloads) and as you see points are weird itself:

[image]

However there is something interesting in `nybb.shp.xml` metadata file:

```
<spdom>
    <bounding>
        <westbc Sync="TRUE">-74.257465</westbc>
        <eastbc Sync="TRUE">-73.699450</eastbc>
        <northbc Sync="TRUE">40.915808</northbc>
        <southbc Sync="TRUE">40.495805</southbc>
    </bounding>
    <lboundng>
        <leftbc Sync="TRUE">913090.770096</leftbc>
        <rightbc Sync="TRUE">1067317.219904</rightbc>
        <bottombc Sync="TRUE">120053.526313</bottombc>
        <topbc Sync="TRUE">272932.050103</topbc>
    </lboundng>
</spdom>
```

I am not familiar with those toolkit (ESRI ArcCatalog), but most probably you need to rescale your points after import using that metadata.